# Can't use outer query's column inside inner query

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query that seems to work if I put a fixed number in the where clause but when I try to replace that number with a column from the outer query, then I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.latest_version_id' in 'where clause'.

I tried all kinds of ways to do this query and re did it 3 times. Please have a look at my query below and see if anyone else can see what I'm doing wrong. I made notes using #####.

Basically, I want to use either `a.latest_version_id` or `b.version_id` (they are both the same value) to filter the results in my sub query. I took the where clause out but that just gives me no results then.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    b.version_id,
    b.title, 
    b.email, 
    b.contact_first_name, 
    b.contact_last_name,
    b.physical_address_1, 
    b.physical_address_2, 
    b.physical_suburb, 
    b.phone_number, 
    b.phone_code, 
    a.latest_version_id,
    c.name,
    f.categories 
FROM 
    products a
LEFT JOIN 
    product_versions b ON a.latest_version_id = b.version_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    product_version_city c ON b.version_id = c.version_id 
    ##### this is the block of code I am struggling with
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT 
         e.version_id, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(d.name SEPARATOR ', ') as categories           
     FROM 
         category_product_version e
     INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              id, name 
          FROM 
              categories) AS d ON d.id = e.category_id 
     WHERE 
         e.version_id = a.latest_version_id ##### the issue is on this line.
        ##### It works if I put '1' there instead of a.latest_version_id
     ) as f ON f.version_id = a.latest_version_id
WHERE 
    b.version_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND b.title IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You have four tables, one is for contacts (c), one is for contact details (b), one is for categories(f) and one is for ?? can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  
    a.version_id,
    a.title, 
    a.email, 
    a.contact_first_name, 
    a.contact_last_name,
    a.physical_address_1, 
    a.physical_address_2, 
    a.physical_suburb, 
    a.phone_number, 
    a.phone_code, 
    a.latest_version_id,
    a.name,
    f.categories 
FROM

(SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    b.version_id,
    b.title, 
    b.email, 
    b.contact_first_name, 
    b.contact_last_name,
    b.physical_address_1, 
    b.physical_address_2, 
    b.physical_suburb, 
    b.phone_number, 
    b.phone_code, 
    a.latest_version_id,
    c.name

FROM products a
    LEFT JOIN product_versions b ON a.latest_version_id = b.version_id 
    LEFT JOIN product_version_city c ON b.version_id = c.version_id) as a


    LEFT JOIN  
    (
       SELECT 
         e.version_id, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(d.name SEPARATOR ', ') as categories           
       FROM category_product_version e
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT id, name FROM categories  
        ) AS d ON d.id = e.category_id 

     ) as f ON f.version_id = a.latest_version_id

 WHERE  f.version_id = a.latest_version_id and a.version_id IS NOT NULL AND a.title IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi @reds , thanks but it still has the same issue as before with a.latest_version_id

Comment: this one "WHERE e.version_id = a.latest_version_id" is your problem. you are using a.latest_version_id but did not declare.. inside the scope. update the answer above just modify if you where clause or not